# Create an object using @Value

Tags: spring-boot, object

I'm trying to use @Value annotation to read a string parameter value and create an object using this value.
I've tried the following:

The parameter in application.yml

```
app:
  report:
    time-zone: +00:00
```

Creating the object using the parameter:

```
@Value("#{ java.time.ZoneId.of('app.report.time-zone') }")
ZoneId reportZoneId;
```

But got the error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reportZoneId':
> Expression parsing failed

Is something wrong with the syntax or isn't it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for the case:

```
@Value("#{T(java.time.ZoneId).of('${app.report.time-zone}')}")
ZoneId reportZoneId;
```